# How do I merge two lists of XElements using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to merge two lists of XElements like so:

list1:

```
<Element name="foo">
    <ChildElement name="childFoo">
        <SubChildElement name="subChildFoo" />
    </ChildElement>
</Element>
<Element name="bar">
    <ChildElement name="childBar">
        <SubChildElement name="subChildBar" />
    </ChildElement>
</Element>
<Element name="zoo" />
```

list2:

```
<Element name="foo" attr="fooAtr" />
<Element name="bar" attr="barAtr" />
<Element name="zoo" attr="barAtr" />
```

and the result should look like this:

```
<Element name="foo" attr="fooAtr">
    <ChildElement name="childFoo">
        <SubChildElement name="subChildFoo" />
    </ChildElement>
</Element>
<Element name="bar" attr="barAtr">
    <ChildElement name="childBar">
        <SubChildElement name="subChildBar" />
    </ChildElement>
</Element>
<Element name="zoo" attr="barAtr" />
```

I tried using the .Concat() method but it just adds them up together:

```
var merged_list = list1.Concat(list2);
```

I want to combine the elements with the same name attribute into one. How can I do this using linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make `list2` into a dictionary and apply the attributes to `list1`?

```
var doc1 = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <root>
        <Element name=""foo"">
            <ChildElement name=""childFoo"">
                <SubChildElement name=""subChildFoo"" />
            </ChildElement>
        </Element>
        <Element name=""bar"">
            <ChildElement name=""childBar"">
                <SubChildElement name=""subChildBar"" />
            </ChildElement>
        </Element>
        <Element name=""zoo"" />
    </root>");

var doc2 = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <root>
        <Element name=""foo"" attr=""fooAtr"" />
        <Element name=""bar"" attr=""barAtr"" />
        <Element name=""zoo"" attr=""barAtr"" />
    </root>");

var attributes = doc2.Descendants("Element")
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("name").Value, e => e.Attribute("attr").Value);
doc1.Descendants("Element")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(e => e.Add(new XAttribute("attr", attributes[e.Attribute("name").Value])));
Console.WriteLine(doc1);
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <Element name="foo" attr="fooAtr">
    <ChildElement name="childFoo">
      <SubChildElement name="subChildFoo" />
    </ChildElement>
  </Element>
  <Element name="bar" attr="barAtr">
    <ChildElement name="childBar">
      <SubChildElement name="subChildBar" />
    </ChildElement>
  </Element>
  <Element name="zoo" attr="barAtr" />
</root>
```

Comment: Hmm I was thinking of using a join and select but this works as well. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a join would do it:

```
var res = from e2 in list2
        join e1 in list1 on e2.name equals e1.name into joined
        from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty() 
            select new Element
            {
                name = j.name, 
                attr = j.attr, 
                ChildElement = j.ChildElement 
            };
```

Comment: this doesn't work for a couple of reasons: wrong syntax for "left join", e1.name should be e1.Attribute("Name").Value, that's not how you create a new XElement.